# ¿Cómo modificar atributo de documento XML c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Necesitó modificar atributos de un documento XML guardado en una ubicación en mi PC

Ejemplo cambiar el valor del elemento id

```
-<ds:Signature Id="Signature-15d7c3e9-a6b4-48be-a9a5-70cbef9dd03d" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Escribí esto pero no me está funcionando:

```
 private string SetAtributo(XmlDocument xmlDoc,string prefix,string uri,string pathSintax,string atributo,string nuevoValor)
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsManager.AddNamespace(prefix,uri);
            XmlNode nodo = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(pathSintax, nsManager);
            if (nodo != null)
            {
               //CODIGO QUE NECESITO
            }
         xmlDoc.Save(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: solo que estructura va tener tu xml para poder ayudar

Comment: Nesecitas todo el documento XML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asignando directamente a la propiedad [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.xmlnode.attributes.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
nodo.Attributes["Id"].Value = "Nuevo Valor";
```

- Distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas `"id"` no es lo mismo que `"Id"`.
- Si el atributo no existe, esto te daría un error de `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

Solo se busca la posicion del atribute con el metodo (Attributes[posicion].Value) y se asigna el valor

```
 private string SetAtributo(XmlDocument xmlDoc,string prefix,string uri,string pathSintax,string atributo,string nuevoValor)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                nsManager.AddNamespace(prefix,uri);
                XmlNode nodo = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(pathSintax, nsManager);
                if (nodo != null)
                {
                    nodo.Attributes[1].Value = nuevoValor;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { result = ex.ToString(); }
            return result;
        }
```